# Picard rank of Shimura varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, shimura-varieties

Let $D$ be a bounded symmetric domain and $\Gamma\subset Aut(D)$ an arithmetic subgroup of automorphisms of $D$. Write $X=\Gamma\backslash D$, it is a connected Shimura variety. Suppose that $X$ is compact. I haven't found in the literature a discussion about the Picard rank of $X$ or about the singular cohomology of $X$ (for instance, what is $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$? What's the rank? Does it have torsion?). Does anyone know any reference for this type of questions?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1974_4_7_2_235_0.pdf) of A. Borel gives some information about real cohomology.

Comment: Minor nitpick : if I remember correctly this locally symmetric variety is not necessarily a Shimura variety. The arithmetic group Gamma should also be congruence, right?

Comment: Ariyan: Yes, you are correct, I was sloppy there.